# Unable to access magento site from anywhere but localhost

Tags: magento, localhost

I have two applications "myapp" and "magento" on my localhost at 192.168.1.110/myapps (A) and 192.168.1.110/magento (B). (A) is an app that I wrote and can be accessed by any computer on our LAN. However, (B) cannot be accessed by anyone except on my computer, localhost.

I haven't done any special port-opening or blocking on Apache or Magento, so I'm puzzled by this. Does anybody have any insight on what might be wrong and where I should look? TIA!

EDIT: in Internet Explorer, the error is just a generic message that says "cannot display this webpage" as if it cannot even recognize the address.

EDIT 2: I tried Firebug as suggested. This is what I'm seeing under the Net tab.
"GET Magento" under URL and "ABORTED" under status. When I hover over with mouse cursor, however, it displays http://127.0.0.1/magento, which is the localhost address.. Is this being http://192.168.1.110/magento being rerouted to http://127.0.0.1/magento?

Comment: When you say you can't access them, what error are you getting? 404, 403?...

Comment: It just say "cannot display webpage" without any code. It looks to me it doesn't see the file at all.

Comment: What does the network tab of firebug, the firefox extension (you're not developing with IE, are you?) show? 404, 403 ?

Comment: @greg0ire: I updated the main post. It looks like the URL is directed to 127.0.0.1/magento when I type in 192.168.1.110/magento.. any idea?

Comment: I think I may have figured out how to change the default secure and unsecure URL.. however, when I changed these values to http://192.168.1.110/magento/, my Magento installation stops working.. oops?

Comment: <sarcasm>"Stops working" is too precise, with so much information, we might even be able to help you fix your problem, which will make disappear all this beautiful mystery.</sarcasm>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the base URL settings in Magento. It sounds like your base URL is set to http://127.0.0.1/magento. When you go to http://192.168.1.110/magento Magento will be called, but it will redirect to http://127.0.0.1/magento which does not work on the remote machine. You should change the base URL in Magento to http://192.168.1.110/magento.

Comment: I think you are right. I actually went and did that, but I accidentally put an extra character at the end of the URL when making this change, and it "broke" my installation (test). I went to core_config_date DB table to manually change the URL, but it still doesn't work, and browser display "The page isn't redirecting properly" in Firefox. It's not a big deal, but I'm wondering why this approach (direct DB manipulation) wouldn't work.

Comment: Changing the URL directly in the core_config_data table should work, just remember to clear the cache afterwards (delete files in var/cache if you can't access admin).