# How can I access a webpage located inside a VM from the host machine's browser?

Tags: windows, magento, centos, virtual-machine

I am able to access the link http://localhost/men/tops-men/jackets-men.html successfully from my VM (configured using X2Go client).

IP Address of the VM: 10.146.106.204

I am also able to ping the VM successfully from my host machine (Windows).

The page that I am trying to access is a php page deployed on Apache Web Server.

However I am not able to do so from my Windows host machine. 
I tried http://10.146.106.204/men/tops-men/jackets-men.html from my Windows machine but it did not work.

Do I have to configure something on my host machine or on my VM ?

Not sure what I am missing.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: @Enigmativity - I am big time fan of SO and spend atleast an hour on it everyday but considering the way technology stack (AWS, Azure, Google AWS, Docker etc) is increasing exponentially there will be non-programming/configuration related questions posted on SO more frequently in the future. Hence, I request to please reconsider your vote.

Comment: It really doesn't matter if others post off-topic questions - that doesn't make them on-topic. The [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) help page says that questions must be "a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development". What you're suggesting is akin to noting that there are many murders each year and, even though murder is illegal, that this means that it is really OK for you to commit murder now too. It's not and everyone else should stop too.

Answer (score 0):

On VM check you can view  http://10.146.106.204/men/tops-men/jackets-men.html

If not you need to configure the web server to listen on that IP (if you're running IIS this is under "bindings" in the right-hand side panel of IIS Manager).

On Host open a cmd window and check you can ping 10.146.106.204

If not check your firewall settings on the VM.

If neither of these 2 things help then you need to add more information about your setup to the question. Those are 2 very simple things you can do to diagnose 2 basic problems you might be having.

Comment: Yes, I can view  http://10.146.106.204/men/tops-men/jackets-men.html the page from my VM successfully and from my host I opened a cmd window and was able to ping 10.146.106.204 successfully as well.

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to solve the problem based on this SO link: [Unable to access magento site from anywhere but localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8190208/unable-to-access-magento-site-from-anywhere-but-localhost)

Updated the DB table core_config_data and updated the data by replacing http://localhost with http://ip-of-vm and then restarted the apache web server.